# DIV fadeIn and position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm writing a plugin to popup a div on a click. I have a hidden div created, and I want to fade it in. However, instead of fading in, it just appears, as if I'd called show(). I'm using the jQuery UI Position tool, so my code looks like this:

```
$('#popover-1'+index).fadeIn('slow').position({
                    of: elem,
                    my: 'center top',
                    at: 'center bottom',
                    offset: '0 10'
                });
```

I thought perhaps I'd try being clever, and changed it to this, but without effect:

```
$('#popover-'+index).fadeIn('slow', function() {
                    $(this).position({
                        of: elem,
                        my: 'center top',
                        at: 'center bottom',
                        offset: '0 10'
                    });
                });
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="person-edit-1"  class='popover bottom' style="display:none;">
  <div class="arrow top" style="position: absolute; "></div>
  <div>Content goes here</div>
</div>
```

The position method won't position non-visible elements, so it didn't work when I called position before fadeIn.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sometimes if the position of the element is set to relative fade doesn't work correctly.  What's your HTML look like?

Comment: I added the HTML to the question. Thanks!

Comment: okay, scratch that idea. Does the fadeIn work if you temporarily remove the .position part of the code?

Comment: Nope. Seems to be exclusive of the positioning.

Comment: (I should mention that fading OUT does work later on when I close the popover).

Comment: So this: `$('#popover-1'+index).fadeIn('slow');` doesn't work?

Comment: Nope, it just appears, which is weird, right?

Comment: yes, very weird. Can you put the surrounding HTML (simplified if need be) and the CSS in? or, reproduce in a fiddle? i suspect some odd obscure style property at work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If jquery-ui position must have it be visible, than you will have to unhide it, position it, re-hide it, and then fade it in.

One option: instead of using fadeIn('slow'), you could position the element, set the opacity to 0, then animate the opacity property. This will only work on browsers that understand the opacity property (not IE):

```
$('#popover-' + index).show().position({
  of: elem,
  my: 'center top',
  at: 'center bottom',
  offset: '0 10'
}).css('opacity', '0').animate({'opacity': '1'}, 'slow');
```

Comment: That works, though what would happen in IE? Would it just show, or would it be something more untoward? (I don't have IE handy to test right now). I'm fine if it just shows in IE.

Comment: You can actually call .show().position().hide().fadeIn(), which is what I ended up doing.